# Shopping cart summary on all website pages

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

I want to add a block with a shopping cart summary in my website.

T So I basically need to retrieve the shopping cart informations and display a brief summary of it. See picture:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/cartSummary.png

How can I implement this ?

Of course, I still have a complete static page with the shopping cart items and full details. But I also want this small block with a small version of the shopping cart.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubercart has its own api for this kind of stuff, create a module with a block using [hook_block](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_block/), then use [uc_cart_get_contents](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/uc_cart_get_contents) to get the cart's contents. This returns an array with all the information in your shopping cart, you can print it out with var_dump or var_export to see what you want from the array.

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal's Ubercart Module

You can use the Cart Block and enable the "Make the shopping cart block collapsible by clicking the name or arrow." feature.

To do this:
Go to /admin/build/block/ find the "Shopping Cart" block and move it where you want it.  Then click the configure link and scroll down until you see a check box with the "Make the shopping cart block collapsible by clicking the name or arrow."  Check the box and you're good to go.  This will display a list of all the products you have in your cart.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ugly, but a working solution (it can be easily customized with a simple CSS coding):

http://www.phpwebcommerce.com/

If you want, I can search for more fancier solutions?

Comment: I forgot to mention (just added in the tags), I'm using Ubercart. So I need a solution for this Drupal module.